# Проект на облачном сервере ловит ошибку

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть телеграмм бот на telebot для работы с большим кол-вом пользователей, версия python-3.10, код на 2500+ строк. Когда загружаю бота на сервер, использую облачный таймвеб, если стоит сменить дайте знать. Если ближе к сути, бот работает около 1-2 дней нормально потом останавливается, я думаю что это происходит из-за сервера, так как бот полностью тестировался от начала до конца и ошибок не было. ***Главный вопрос, можно ли сделать как то чтоб когда происходит ошибка бот либо создавал текстовый файл в который ее записывает либо как то давал понять что произошло и почему программа остановилась.*** В try except весь код ведь запихнуть не получится, а где происходит ошибка и какая она даже близко представления нет.

Answer (score 0):

Была та же ошибка, помогло вот это, буду рад, если и вам поможет:

```
try:
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
except Exception as e:
    time.sleep(3)
    print(e)
```

Comment: Попробую и отпишу, заранее благодарю

Comment: К сожалению помогло частично, с while True возникли проблемы, а вот точно такой же код но без цикла сработал как нужно, спасибо

Comment: Очень рад, можете отметить как правильный(зелёная галочка)